# How to disable server signature on wordpress?

Tags: php, apache

i am trying to turn off server signature on wordpress.
in htaccess file add following line:  `ServerSignature Off`
But when i check http://security.firewallmonitor.org it says it is not turned off.
I use shared hosting with cpanel, but can i disable server signature? i did not find apache in cpnale. How can i disable it?

Comment: This is a server setting. WordPress has nothing to do with that. :)